# Indistinguishable Balls Into Indistinguishable, Limited-Sized Bins

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, balls-in-bins

I have the following experiment

> There are m indistinguishable balls and n indistinguishable bins of size s.  For each ball, we pick a bin.  If the bin still has capacity, the ball is placed inside it.  If the bin is full, the ball is discarded.

What I am curious to discover is the probability distribution of the total number of balls in all of bins at the end of the experiment.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of having $M$ balls in the bins at the end of the experiment is:
$$
p(M)=\frac1{n^m}\sum_{0\le m_i}^{\substack{\sum_i m_i=m \\\ \sum_i\min(m_i,s)=M}}
\binom m{m_1,m_2,\dots,m_n},
$$
where $i$ takes on the values from $1$ to $n$.