# Number of ways to put N indistiguishable balls into k indistinguishable boxes of limited size.

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

I've seen how to put N balls into k distinguishable boxes with no size limit (e.g. the multiplicity of an Einstein solid) where ${{N+k-1} \choose {k}}$ is the multiplicity. However, these boxes are both distinguishable and have no size limit.

I found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707996/number-of-ways-to-distribute-indistinguishable-balls-into-distinguishable-boxes) that talks about how to handle the issue of size limit, but not indistinguishability. I also do not quite understand the use of generating functions.

I also found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2557466/indistinguishable-balls-into-indistinguishable-limited-sized-bins) which seems similar, but I do not wish to throw away any balls.

Any ideas?

Comment: You may wish to look up [twelvefold way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way#Intuitive_meaning_of_the_chart_using_Balls_and_Boxes_scenario).

Comment: Look up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory), in particular,   Partitions in a rectangle and Gaussian binomial coefficients